# Dockerize your Angular NodeJS application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nginx, docker

We have an front-end application. 
It's written in Angular (html + css + javascript) which needs to be hosted by a webserver (nginx).
Angular is communicating with a NodeJs server which will communicate with the backend.

Now we have to run this in Docker.

- We want to use 2 Docker containers: one with nodejs and one with nginx and let them work together

So is it possible to write 2 dockerfiles in the one repository?
The main idea is to have 1 dockerfile for nodejs which is also running the bower install, npm install, ...
which will look like this:

```
# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/www
WORKDIR /usr/src/www

RUN npm install -g bower
RUN npm install -g gulp

# Install app dependencies
COPY . /usr/src/www/
RUN bower install
RUN npm install
RUN gulp build

EXPOSE port
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

And one dockerfile in which we run a nginx-webserver but will also include a nginx.conf so it can point to the right /dist folder in our node.js-container
The dockerfile of nginx will look like this:

```
# Set nginx base image
FROM nginx

# Copy custom configuration file from the current directory
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

An example of the nginx.conf

```
location ~* /dist {
            proxy_pass http://nodejs:port;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
```

Comment: Can someone confirm if this is a right approach of how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Using 2 docker containers is the best option in my opinion, single responsibility per container design is worth to follow.

It's very common having to create more than one container per project:

- database
- backend server
- frontend server

One approach is create a folder for docker definitions and for each docker context, create an script `docker_build.sh` that prepares the docker context (copy all the artifacts required: libs, source code, etc) and finally make the docker build.

```
project_root/
|----src/
|----docker/
|----|----angular/
|----|----|-----Dockerfile
|----|----|-----docker_build.sh
|----|----nodejs/
|----|----|-----Dockerfile
|----|----|-----docker_build.sh
```

An example of docker_build.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# create temp directory for building
mkdir DockerBuildTempPath/

# copy files to temp directory
cp -arv Dockerfile DockerBuildTempPath/
cp -arv ../../src/ DockerBuildTempPath/
# ... etc

cd DockerBuildTempPath

#build image
docker build -t myapp .

# remove temp directory
cd ..
rm -r ./DockerBuildTempPath/
```

Comment: where are you storing the package.json Because it contains dependencies for nodejs AND angular.

Comment: `package.json` is under `src` directory along with all other app stuff. The idea of the bash script is copy temporarily all those stuff, build docker image, and the delete them

Comment: I'm doing this with jenkins. (so as replacements voor the .sh). Would you recommend to perform the npm install in the jenkins-folder or in the image itself (dockerfile)?

Comment: I'd recommend performing the npm install in the docker image

Comment: Never try to run npm install or yarn install inside the image. When it comes to scaling and creating multiple containers, the last thing you want is hundreds of images downloading lots of data at startup. You should always aim to serve the final production builds inside your Docker images. From this guide: https://medium.com/@DenysVuika/your-angular-apps-as-docker-containers-471f570a7f2

Answer (score 0):

Try jwilder/nginx-proxy(https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy). I'm currently using it to host a main docker Nginx that proxys for all my other docker services.

Comment: Not an answer, seems more appropriate to be a comment